# Google play Upload/publish "apk" types

Tags: android, google-play

What are the differences between `beta, alpha and production` ?

It is possible to move from alpha or beta to production ?

You can upload an apk production and hide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the differences between beta, alpha and production ?

`beta` and `alpha` are testing channels which is not available to public on playstore app. The apps under these channel are available only to your testers.

> Alpha testing group users are eligible for the alpha, beta, or
>   production version of your app with the highest version code that is
>   compatible with their device. Beta testing group users are only
>   eligible for the beta or production version of your app with the
>   highest version code that is compatible with their device.

`apps` in production are available to anyone who uses comes to playstore (provided you've chosen to distribute in the user's region) production

Read this [Google help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) for a detailed overview of each.

> It is possible to move from alpha or beta to production ?

Yes, you will get a direct upload to do that against each apk in alpha/beta. Tou can also move directly from alpha to production (skipping beta) if you want.

> You can upload an apk production and hide ?

No, once in production is there. You can only update it or unpublish it. Unpublishing is like hiding. (if that is what you meant - you can later republish it.) But, then you wont be able to also publish alpha or beta i guess.

Comment: Hi, @AndroidMechanic, can I move after beta to production ? I want know if I can publish first time in beta after final (production), or I need do a new  app?

Comment: I have final version, but I need pusblish apk in mode hide for now

Comment: no that is not possible. Check updated answer with details about your other two questions.

Comment: Nice, last question : if you put apk in beta, not is visible in google not ?

Comment: only to users who are in your beta testing groups. Go to the beta tab and you'll see the links explaining this in details there itself.